# passing values across functions yields no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have the code below where I use python package `click` to fetch some input from user. I then pass the user input to a function that has code to load a pre-trained model. I return a list of values that I pass to a second function that generates text using the model and other values. However the values aren't passed from first function to the second because when I try to print the list I get nothing. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong, thanks a lot!!

```
@click.argument('email_template', nargs=1)
def load_model(email_template):
    ## code block here
    list1 = [email_template, value1, value2]
    return list1


def generate_text(value2):
    # code block here
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = load_model()
    list2 = generate_text(list1)
    print(list2)
```

Comment: Typo `email template`, remember the underscores. Also, the line `list1 = []` is not needed, and remember to pass in an argument when you run the code

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `@click.command()` decorator. It is not enough to use `@click.argument()`, then expect this to work. The `@click.command()`-decorated function becomes the *entry point* of your script, and should not be seen as something that'll return the user options.

Also, if `email_template` is the only option your script takes and it expects just one value, there is no point in using `nargs=1`.

So do this:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('email_template')
def load_model(email_template):
    ## code block here
    # This is your *main script function*.

    list1 = [email_template, value1, value2]

    # don't return, continue the work you need doing from here
    list2 = text_generator(list1)
    print(list2)

def generate_text(result):
    # code block here
    return value2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_model()
```

When `load_model` exits, your script exits.

Also, rather than use `print()`, consider using [`click.echo()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#echoing), especially when you need to print text that uses non-ASCII characters and needs to work on a variety of platforms, or if you want to include ANSI colors in your output.

Comment: I had the `@click.command()` in my code, forgot to include here. But calling the second function in the first did the trick. Was able to get the code up and running. Thanks a ton for the quick help!!